# How do I remove the menuArrow in a Select widget in gwt-bootstrap3?

Tags: css, gwt, gwtbootstrap3

I have been trying to conditionally remove the menu arrow at the end of a Select box in my current project which uses gwt-bootstrap3.

I have tried the following options:

```
<select:Select ui:field="fieldName" name="fieldName" b:id="fieldName" showMenuArrow="false">
    <select:Option ui:field="option1" text="option1Text"/>
</select:Select>
```

I have also tried via the api, using

`fieldName.setShowMenuArrow(false);`

I am mainly looking to disable this menu arrow when I would like to indicate that this selector is disabled and that options are not available for select dropdown.

On inspecting element via the browser:I noticed that within the div for the select box there are other divs/spans and one nested as a child of the main selector div specifically with the

`<span class="caret"></span>`

On removing this class name I could make the menuArrow disappear. 
However accessing the specific span tag with this caret class using a querySelector and then making sure this is the right one (from the entire page which has other such selectors too) seems a slight challenge and unwieldy.
Here's a snippet from the inspectElement on chrome.
[inspecting the Select element and the span with caret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtC6t.png)

This seems like a bug in the menuArrow handling for the Selector and if it is indeed one, can anyone suggest a workaround until fixed?. Appreciate your suggestions/answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setShowMenuArrow` method is for something else: it turns on/off this arrow:

[image: menu arrow on select]

If you want to hide caret on all disabled Select boxes you could try with css:

```
.bootstrap-select.disabled .caret {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide it only some of them, first add new class name, for example `no-caret-on-disabled` and use this:

```
.bootstrap-select.disabled.no-caret-on-disabled .caret {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam for pointing out that the setShowMenuArrow was the one to the left. Spent quite some time figuring out why the caret wouldn't disappear after I would set it to false. On looking into the Styles in the inspect panel in firefox I noticed the selector was something similar to what you mentioned. I had to specifiy `.bootstrap-select.form-control.disabled .caret` and then on getting the element through a jsni method with the above selector string, I removed className 'caret' and voila, it was gone. Thanks much!